# Is there an equation for an ellipse as a function of a velocity vector, radius and vector towards the foci.

Tags: vector-analysis, mathematical-modeling, projectile-motion

Trying to model the orbit of electrons around an atom I have used the Rodrigues Rotation formula to rotate the electrons. Now I am dealing with ellipses and I am wondering if there is a rotation formula for ellipses. There are three vectors in play; velocity vector, distance between proton and electron vector and another vector that indicates where the electron tends to go. Usually is towards the proton and it’s simple circular motion but is there a way of rotating g the electron knowing these three vectors ?

Comment: "Rotation" must be understood now with respect to one of the foci (and the word "rotation" should no longer be used) just as you would do in celestial mechanics with a planet moving around the sun (focus) with a polar description of the motion $p=\dfrac{p_0}{1+cos(\theta)}$

Comment: The acceleration should be toward the proton in the elliptical orbit also. The difference is that we never have the velocity and acceleration so well balanced as in circular motion, where they are orthogonal and the acceleration is just exactly enough so that the radius of curvature of the path equals the distance to the proton.